# How bad is it to use Node_load in a loop in drupal 7?

Tags: caching

Something like:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $node = node_load($i);
    print $node->fieldYouWant;
}
```

That is a lot easier to read, gives you access to all the fields etc. However, in a loop, I would imagine Drupal would fall over? Or is the built in caching sufficient to not have to worry about it?

Comment: I'd say Clive's answer is the correct one, and there is really no generic way to answer you actual question. Whether you need to worry about loading 100 nodes separately depends entirely on your setup, server load, and 100 other factors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should never need to use `node_load()` in a loop, that's what [`node_load_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) is for:

```
$nids = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
foreach (node_load_multiple($nids) as $node) {
  ...
}
```

It's hard to imagine a scenario where loading the nodes individually would be necessary or desirable.

Comment: I you have *a lot* of nodes to work on, then loading as `$node = node_load($nid, NULL, FALSE);` can keep the static cache mostly empty, which can help keep memory footprint low.  This can make a big difference with bulk operations.

Answer (score 6):

In response to MDP's comment you can use node_load_multiple & keep the memory usage low by using [node_load_multiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) in increments of 100 or so & you get the speed benefit of bulk loading. [array_chunk](http://php.net/array-chunk) is key

```
// Generate an array 1-1000.
$nids = range(1, 1000);
// Split $nids array into chunks of 100
$nids_chunked = array_chunk($nids, 100, TRUE);
// Only load 100 at a time.
foreach ($nids_chunked as $chunk) {
  $nodes = node_load_multiple($chunk, array(), TRUE);
  if (!empty($nodes)) {
    // Do work on each $node object.
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      echo $node->nid . ' ';
    }
  }
}
// Free memory.
unset($nodes);
```

Also I'll plug my sandbox module if you're looking to extract just a field value from a node, [EntityFieldQueryExtra](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mikeytown2/2209909). IF you know [how to use EFQ](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/entityfieldquery-let-drupal-do-the-heavy-lifting-pt-1/), then using EFQE should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: If you've got a minute would you mind posting this as an answer to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/130089/how-to-load-a-large-amount-of-users as well, and maybe updating for user entities (or let me know and I'll do the edit)? It's a really useful snippet and I think it's worth the duplication, but you should be getting the credit for the solution. Thanks!